# Winsorize within groups of dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],
                   [1,4],
                   [1,5],
                   [2,65],
                   [2,34],
                   [2,23],
                   [2,45]], columns = ['label', 'score'])
```

Is there an efficient way to create a column `score_winsor` that winsorises the score column within the groups at the 1% level?

I tried this with no success:

```
df['score_winsor'] = df.groupby('label')['score'].transform(lambda x: max(x.quantile(.01), min(x, x.quantile(.99))))
```

Comment: Have you looked at [scipy's implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize.html)?  Have you looked up anything?  What problem are you running into with your current approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
df['score_winsor'] = df.groupby('label')['score'].transform(lambda x: np.maximum(x.quantile(.01), np.minimum(x, x.quantile(.99))))
```

Output

```
print(df.to_string())

   label  score  score_winsor
0      1      2          2.04
1      1      4          4.00
2      1      5          4.98
3      2     65         64.40
4      2     34         34.00
5      2     23         23.33
6      2     45         45.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [scipy's implementation of winsorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize.html#scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize)

```
df["score_winsor"] = df.groupby('label')['score'].transform(lambda row: winsorize(row, limits=[0.01,0.01]))
```

Output

```
>>> df
   label  score  score_winsor
0      1      2             2
1      1      4             4
2      1      5             5
3      2     65            65
4      2     34            34
5      2     23            23
6      2     45            45
```

Comment: This doesn't take groups into account.